# Website to select from drop down list with mixed English and Arabic characters

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, web, non-ascii-characters

I have a list on website that has on each line a mixed English and Arabic. I tried

```
ieApp.Document.forms(0).all("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlManufacturer").Value = "Chevrolet ~ شيفروليه"
```

I also tried to put the expression into Excel cell and reference it in the code:

```
ieApp.Document.forms(0).all("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlManufacturer").Value = Range("a7")
```

Neither solution works. Here is the code for the list:

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlManufacturer" id="ddlManufacturer" style="width:270px;">
        <option value="">---Select Manufacturer---</option>
        <option value="1">Acura ~ اكيورا</option>
        <option value="2">Aston Martin ~ استون مارتن</option>
        <option value="3">Audi ~ اودي</option>
        <option value="4">BAIC ~ بايك</option>
        <option value="5">BAW ~ بي ايه دبليو</option>
        <option value="6">Bentley ~ بنتلي </option>
        <option value="7">BMW ~ بي ام دبليو</option>
        <option value="8">Brilliance ~ بريليانس</option>
        <option value="9">BYD ~ بي واي دي</option>
        <option value="10">Cadillac ~ كاديلاك</option>
        <option value="11">Changan ~ تشانجان</option>
        <option value="12">Chery ~ تشيري</option>
        <option value="13">Chevrolet ~ شيفروليه</option>
</select>
```

I have other list on that website that have only English and have no problem selecting them. I do not want to use .selectedindex=13 since the list can change over time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this an internal URL?

Comment: no but you need login which I coded and it works